# Android new permissions model - Do all the granted permissions are revoked by moving to the new model?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I have an app in the store which targets SDK 22 (the old permissions model).
What happens, from a user perspective, if I update my app to target SDK 23 supporting the new permissions model? Do all the already granted permissions will be revoked and the user will be requested for a permission again?

Thanks.

Comment: Below 23 No permission are requested at run-time.But at 23 user can deny  the permission at any time and you have to ask for the permission if it is not approved.If it is approved you don't have to ask for the permission again.

Comment: For more information you can check this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: I fully understand that. I'm asking what happens if my user had my app when it was target SDK 22 and then updates my (which now targets SDK 23). By moving to SDK 23, all the permissions which were granted before the updated, will be revoked?

Comment: No they will not revoked again.